# Newtonsoft Json - Deserialize - Custom mapping if property name is same but property type is different

Tags: c#, .net, rest, serialization, json.net

I'm calling the REST API to get the object as ResponseData.

```
CustomField CustomFieldObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomField>(ResponseData.ToString());
```

// Class defination (`DataType` is of type `int?`)

```
public class CustomField {
 public int? DataType {get; set;}
}
```

API is having the object like this (`DataType` is of type `string`)

```
public class ResposeData {
     public string DataType {get; set;}
    }
```

Now, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is throwing the error because of different data type (string cannot be converted to int).
So, how can I ignore these properties with different data types while deserializing?

Comment: Post the JSON string and the exact error. Although, if you are trying to convert `"someString123"` to an integer, you are doing it wrong. If the API wanted that field to be a number instead of string, they would have serialized it as a number. For example, a phone number may look like an int if you omit extensions and international codes, but treating it as an int is definitely a bug

Comment: yes, that's what exactly happening. How can I customize the mapping for some specific properties?

Comment: I can't change any of the objects type.. so I have to customize it somehow while deserializing. Is there any parameter which I can pass for this?

Comment: No code, no JSON, no error, no way one can answer. You *CAN'T* deserialize `123sd` to an int. Are you *sure* the text can be parsed as an integer at all?  Besides, if the object created to call an API have the wrong type, you should fix that bug, not try to cover it up. Otherwise, you'll have to create *new* objects that can read the input, filter out those that can't be parsed and map the rest to your existing objects

Comment: ok I'm updating the question

Answer (score 0):

The complicated answer is that you can specify converters to use in the deserialisation process:  `JsonConverter`.

The basics is, you can use `JsonConverter` as the base class and override these properties:

```
public class KeysJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public KeysJsonConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)t;
            IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

            o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));

            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }
}
```

This is an [extract](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) from James Newton-King.

If you wish to read the JSON into the object, then you will be looking to override the `ReadJson` and the `CanRead` methods.

If you wish to specify that this converter can read the json, override the `CanRead` method and return true.

Then you will need to override the `ReadJson` method in order to read the values out.

The [source code for other converters](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters) will help you out somewhat in how to implement the `ReadJson`, but be aware you will be using reflection.